# Songs from YouTube that are downloaded through python program can not be synchronized with iTunes

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, windows, itunes

I have "written" a python program that downloads the audio of a YouTube video in mp3 format. The downloading procedure works fine but I can only listen to the songs on my windows laptop. I would like to synchronize these songs with iTunes (download-able in MS store) so I can listen to them on my iphone. Whenever I try to drag the songs into the iTunes album directory it does not work and it shows a black circle with a diagonal line in it. I tried to play the songs on my iphone by uploading them to wetransfer and downloading them to my device. The slider moved from left to the ride but you could not hear anything. Could you help me please I have also enabled the one crucial option in the iTunes application but this had no impact on the functionality. Could some unnecessarily saved meta data prevent me from importing them to itunes library? (In my country it is totally legal to download music from yt if it is for the private use.)

Here is the code:

```
import youtube_dl

def get_mp3():
    video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
        url = input("Enter video URL: "), download = False
    )
    
    options = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'keepvideo': False,
        'outtmpl': f"{video_info['title']}.mp3",
    }
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
        ydl.download([video_info['webpage_url']])

get_mp3()
```

Comment: So you can hear audio on your computer, jut not on the phone?

Comment: Yes exactly I can hear it on my laptop but it remains silent on my phone. But as I said: no way to import it into the music app of apple. Uploaded it on wetransfer and downloaded it on my iphone saved in files but no sound.

Comment: Sorry, more clarification. Is the goal to add it to itunes programmatically, or are you unable to add it manually?

Comment: I want to drag it in the itunes library, so i would say it´s a manual problem. It can be played on laptop but i am unable to synchronize with itunes app available in microsoft store.